# Change virtual property

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently working on some existing C# code and i simply want to set a property to `null` when a given code doesn't exist in the system.

The code i currently have looks like this:

```
if (!CodeExists(SomeClass.Code))
{
    SomeClass.Code = null;
}
```

So assume that `SomeClass.Code` starts with a value of `100`. It then checks if that `Code` exists with the method `CodeExists()`. If it can't find the code it should set `SomeClass.Code = null`.

But when i step through this piece of code with the debugger then i see that `SomeClass.Code` doesn't change at all, eventhough the debugger comes inside the `if` statement.

When i look at the property `Code` i see that it is declared as `virtual`:

```
public virtual CodeNumber Code { get; set; }
```

Does that mean i cannot simply change the value when it is declared as `virtual`? Is there anything i can do to change that value of `Code`?

---

Seems some other part of the code is the problem:

```
public SomeClassProjection SomeClass
{
    get
    {
        // some stuff is done here
        SomeClassState.Value = queryProcessor
                    .Execute(new ExistingProductsQuery { OrderNumber = SelectedOrderNumber });

        return SomeClassState.Value;
    }
}
```

So `SomeClassState` is returned. And that is defined like this:

```
public ViewValue<SomeClassProjection> SomeClassState;
```

So it does use another class like some of you suggested. And `ViewValue` clearly tells it is `readyonly`. That means i have to take another approach, but at least i now know what actually is prevents me from editting that property and that `virtual` has nothing to do with it.

---

About this topic:

So how do i accept an answer now that i found the solution? Or do i need to close this topic?

Comment: [Virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) is not the cause of that.

Comment: `virtual` just means "it can be overridden". And this might be the case. You have to verify whether or not you really have an object of type `SomeClass` there or an inheritor. Another question is, what type is `CodeNumber`? Class or value type?

Comment: @oddparity `CodeNumber` is defined as a `public class`. And `SomeClass` really seems to be of type `SomeClass`. In the debugger it shows: `SomeClass {CompanyName.Path.Projections.SomeClass}` when i hold my cursor on the object.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right object?

Comment: as previously stated virtual is not the problem. I would check if there are other places where Code is set.

Comment: Try setting Code to some another "not null" value just to make sure Code is not written to avoid null values(which is sometime common). It might be the case if the implementation you are seeing for code is just metadata.

Comment: I editted my post, found out where to object came from and that also showed me whu i can't edit it.

Comment: Type up your own answer below and accept that if you found the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Seems some other part of the code is the problem:

```
public SomeClassProjection SomeClass
{
    get
    {
        // some stuff is done here
        SomeClassState.Value = queryProcessor
                    .Execute(new ExistingProductsQuery { OrderNumber = SelectedOrderNumber });

        return SomeClassState.Value;
    }
}
```

So `SomeClassState` is returned. And that is defined like this:

```
public ViewValue<SomeClassProjection> SomeClassState;
```

So it does use another class like some of you suggested. And `ViewValue` clearly tells it is `readyonly`. That means i have to take another approach, but at least i now know what actually is prevents me from editting that property and that `virtual` has nothing to do with it.